# How do I reset my key chain on Mac High Sierra?

Tags: macos, password, keychain, high-sierra

I'm using Mac High Sierra.  How do I reset my key chain?  I went in to the "Keychain Access" application, clicked on the "Reset My Default Key Chains" button and then entered my login password, but get the message

```
Unable to obtain authorization for this operation.
```

What do I need to do to reset my keychain?  I know I'm entering the right password because when I enter the same one in a termiainl using "sudo" it accepts it.